# ~ in CSS but for all HTML tags

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
input:focus ~ p {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<p>Please click on the input!</p>
```

I want to make `p` red (only with CSS) but input is in `div`...

Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can not traverse up the DOM tree in CSS you would have to use JavaScript, your CSS would work if you markup was just

```
<input type="text" />
<p>Please click on the input!</p>
```

Although that would make all siblings and children of siblings P tags after your input red

but if you were using the above markup then it would be safer to use the below CSS which would only select the next sibling:

```
input:focus + p {
   color: red;
}
```

If you used jQuery 1.7+ with your original markup you could do:

```
$( "input" ).on('focus', function() {
  $(this).parent().next().css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: And how can I make `p` not red if input isn't focused?

Comment: Blur is the event that is triggered when an input looses focus so you could use $( "input" ).on('blur', function() {$(this).parent().next().css('color','');}); to remove the color value